# Why can't I purchase more of the same weapon?

Tags: fable

So I bought Fable: The Lost Chapters on Steam during the year-end sale.  However, I can't seem to purchase multiple of the same type of weapon - for weapons I've already purchased, the entry on the vendor list is grayed out.  The vendors *do* have sufficient inventory for me to buy the item.

I'm trying to maintain a bit of a theme here; is there any way for me to be able make these purchases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Fable, you cannot own more than one of the same weapon or item of clothing.

Comment: This is what I suspect, but do you have any references for this?  I'd appreciate something official, if it exists.  I find this restriction stupid and annoying - especially because I could have sworn I was given a duplicate of something after I'd previously bought one.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse It's possible you received a variation of what you already had, like "Dark Mage Robes" when you already have "Light Mage Robes" or something like that.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse You can find duplicates in chests or from certain events but you don't receive another item.